# Hide grouped column headers?

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-php

How can grouped column headers be hidden?

What I mean is turning this:

[image]

... into this:

[image]

[Documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping#options_and_methods) didn't help unfortunately.

Grouping [demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/grouping/grphead1/default.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [destroyGroupHeader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agroupingheadar#destroying_group_header) method.

Comment: @JessStone: You should understand that jqGrid is **pure JavaScript product** (to be exactly it's jQuery plugin). So the most parts of PHP code just generates JavaScript code. It is doesn't important whether you find the method like `$grid->destroyGroupHeader()` in jqSuite for PHP or not. You still can use it. Look at the documentation [here](http://www.trirand.net/documentation/php/_2v90ju98u.htm) or [here](http://www.trirand.net/documentation/php/_2v90jr1py.htm) to understand how to mix PHP code with JavaScript code.